# Python not able to import .csv file

Tags: python, csv, file-io

```
import nltk.classify.util
import csv
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
classifier.show_most_informative_features()

data = csv.DictReader(open('twitter_data_Trump.csv', 'r'))
print data.fieldnames
for each in data:
    row = {}

    otuput.append(row)
    print output
```

I am very new to Python and am having trouble trying to figure out how to use the Movie Reviews Classifier to classify my imported .csv file. I keep receiving an error message saying: "No such file or directory." Any idea on how I can fix this? I am trying to read in a .csv file and basically assign positive and negatives to tweets that are contained in the csv file. I am not sure if my code works and accomplishes the task at hand.

Comment: The error is quite self explainatory - you give incorrect path to the file, this has nothing to do with nltk or classifier - you simply try to open a file which does not exist (in terms of local paths etc.)

Comment: To open your .csv file, your python script must be located in the same directory. Otherwise, you need to change data = csv.DictReader(open('twitter_data_Trump.csv', 'r')) to "data = csv.DictReader(open( '<more_specific_path>/twitter_data_Trump.csv', 'r'))"

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. I used the absolute path, but it seems like something is wrong in my .csv file. Is there any way I can read through a .txt file?